# How can i remap a non-ascii keyboard character in evil-mode?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, evil-mode

I would like to remap the key "é" on my keyboard to `ctrl-w` in emacs evil-mode (doom emacs)

I tried with

```
(define-key evil-operator-state-map "é" "\C-w") 
;; and
(global-set-key "é" "\C-w")
```

But none of these worked.

Is what I'm trying to do possible ?

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```lisp
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "é") (kbd "C-w"))
```

1. Use `(kbd KEY-SEQUENCE)`, where `KEY-SEQUENCE` is what Emacs tells you the key sequence is.
2. Use `key-translation-map` to translate keys. See the Elisp manual, node [Translation Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html).